# How to Resolve out of memory error in Matlab?

Tags: windows, matlab, out-of-memory

I implemented a matlab code that reads a wav file and do some analysis on it.
The size of the wav file is about (3-4 G).
when I run the file I get the following error:

```
"Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options"
```

I tried to increase the virtual memory, but it didn't work.
Following is the code I am using:

```
event=0;
[x, fs] = wavread('C:\946707752529.wav');
Ts=1/fs;%  sampling period 
N = length(x);% N is the number of samples
slength = N*Ts;%slength is the length of the sound file in seconds


% Reading the first 180 seconds and find the energy, then set a threshold value
calibration_samples = 180 * fs;
[x2, Fs] = wavread('C:\946707752529.wav', calibration_samples);
Tss=1/Fs;
[b,a]=butter(5,[200 800]/(Fs/2));
y2=filter(b,a,x2);


%This loop is to find the average energy of the samples for the first 180 seconds
startSample=1;
endSample=Fs;
energy=0;
 for i=1:180

    energy=energy+sum(y2(startSample:endSample).^2)*Tss;
    startSample=endSample+1;
    endSample=endSample+Fs;

 end
 mean_energy=energy/180;
 Reference_Energy=mean_energy;% this is a reference energy level
 Threshold=0.65*Reference_Energy;


% Now filtering the whole recorded file to be between [200-800] Hz
[b,a]=butter(5,[200 800]/(fs/2));
y=filter(b,a,x);
N = length(y);
N=N/fs; % how many iteration we need


startSample=1;
endSample=fs;
energy=0;
j=1;
 while( j<=N)
    counter=0;
    energy=sum(y(startSample:endSample).^2)*Ts;

    if (energy<=Threshold)
        counter=counter+1;

        for k=1:9

            startSample=endSample+1;
            endSample=endSample+fs;
            energy=sum(y(startSample:endSample).^2)*Ts;

               if (energy<=Threshold)
                   counter=counter+1;

               else 
                   break;
               end %end inner if
        end % end inner for



    end % end outer IF
     if(counter>=10)
        event=event+1;

     end
    if(counter>0)
        j=j+counter;
    else
        j=j+1;
    end
    startSample=endSample+1;
    endSample=endSample+fs;

 end % end outer For
```

System: Windows 7 64 bit
RAM: 8 GB
Matlab: 2013

Comment: Maybe related http://askubuntu.com/q/799834/25388

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your code this might work:

- After reading in the file remove everything except the first 180 secs
- Determine the treshold value
- Clear memory of everything except the first piece of data
- Analyse the piece of data and store the result
- Clear memory of everything except the next piece of data...

This is assuming that your algorithm is correct and efficient.

It may also be the case that your algorithm has a problem, to detect this please run the code with `dbstop if error` and check the size of all variables when it errors out. Then just check whether one of them is much too big and you may have found the mistake.

Comment: @user1773886 
thank you for your help. following are some notes about your suggestions:

regarding the read of wav file, the first vector contains the whole recorded file. On the other hand, the second one contains only 30 sec of the recorded file.

calibration_samples = 30; 
[x2, Fs] = wavread('C:\946707752529.wav', calibration_samples);

so the second vector should not consume the memory. Am I right ?

for vectorization, I have viewed the link provided, and tried to change my code based on it, but I think it could not be changed. for example:

Comment: In my code I am using:

 for i=1:30
     
    energy=energy+sum(y2(startSample:endSample).^2)*Tss;
    startSample=endSample+1;
    endSample=endSample+Fs;

 end

This part of code calculates the energy of windows of length Fs(frequency rate).

I tried to use "cumsum" function as mentioned in the link:

energy=energy+cumsum(y2,Fs)^2*Tss;

but the problem is how can I move in windows ?? first I need 1-->Fs, then Fs-->2Fs and so on


I will try to use "dbstop if error" and see what I will get

Comment: @user983722,,,,I have used dbstop if error, and got the error in wavread function, it throws an exception within the wavread function:
catch exception
    fclose(fid);
    throw(exception);
end
Any Idea?

Comment: @user1741938 Can you then look at all variables in all open workspaces and chedk whether there are some surprisingly big ones?

Answer (score 2):

I guess wavread actually stores all data of the wave file into system memory. Moreover it may add extra informations.

I see that you are calling this function two times, storing results in different matrices, so as your file is 3-4G, you need at least 6-8G of memory. However your OS, Matlab and maybe other programs also need some memory, that's why you have this out of memory error.

One solution is to divide the WAV file into multiple files and read them separately. Another solution is to call wavread only once, and use the loaded data wherever you need it, but without reallocating new memory for that.

Comment: damn, ninja'd me. :D +1 to reusing `x`. And another tip: for loops should be avoided in Matlab where possible, for performance reasons. use [vectorization](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) instead. also, your for loops don't make use of the index character, which is a big indicator that the operation can be done more efficiently with vectorization/matrix operations.

Comment: @Christoph Vectorization is likely to speed things up, however doing one small thing at a time will typically not require more memory than doing everything at once.

Comment: memory, no. cpu cycles, yes. ;-) (yeah it's not 100% to the question, I just saw it in the code and this is a Bad Thing to do in Matlab), so I thought it worth mentioning.